# Is there a way to get the DefaultProperty metadata at runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

I'm trying to get the DefaultProperty metadata for a class in ActionScript but I can't find any mention of the DefaultProperty in the metadata XML.

I'm using the following code:

```
var describedTypeRecord:DescribeTypeCacheRecord = mx.utils.DescribeTypeCache.describeType(BorderContainer);
var typeDescription:* = describedTypeRecord.typeDescription;
```

The XML is long but here the first node it returns:

```
<type name="spark.components::BorderContainer" base="spark.components::SkinnableContainer" isDynamic="false" isFinal="false" isStatic="false">
```

The default property for BorderContainer or SkinnableContainer is `mxmlContentFactory`:

```
[DefaultProperty("mxmlContentFactory")]
```

I've also tried RichText. The default property for this is "content":

```
[DefaultProperty("content")]
```

It doesn't seem to show anything about it in the metadata.

In the compiler options I have included the compiler arguments:

```
-keep-as3-metadata+=DefaultProperty
```

Comment: I am getting defaultProperty metadatatag for Richtext. <metadata name="DefaultProperty">
      <arg key="" value="content"/>
    </metadata>  mxmlContentFactory is DefaultProperty for SkinnableContainer  and it is showing it in the generated xml for SkinnableContainer but not for BorderContainer

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes they are declared on super classes. I had to walk the parent classes and check each one to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not set on some classes but if it is defined it will be defined on the super classes.

I was checking BorderContainer but it was defined on a SkinnableContainer:

```
<metadata name="DefaultProperty">
  <arg key="" value="mxmlContentFactory"/>
</metadata>
```

The code I have posted works when it's defined on the main class. If a class doesn't have a default property I would get a list of all the super classes and check each one until I got to object or UIComponent.